# Delete working but not redirect a link page in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I want to delete status comment.
My `route`:

```
Route::get('/delete-comment/{id}/', [
'uses' => 'classroom@getDeleteComment',
'as' => 'Comment.delete',
'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

My `controller`:

```
public function getDeleteComment(Request $request,$id)
    {

        $class_id = $request->get('class_id');
        $comment = StatusComments::where('id', $id)->first();

        $comment->delete();


        Flash::success('Successfuly deleted your comment!');
        return redirect(route('class',['class_id'=>$class_id]));
    }
```

My delete-link:

```
<a href="{{ route('Comment.delete', ['id' => $comment->id]) }}" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

When i delete click opption it's give me the error. My link genarate http://localhost:8000/class But here should to come http://localhost:8000/class/69. Where 69 is page link that is genarate by classrooms table id. That's why i already insert a class_id field in status table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your route to include `class_id`:

```
Route::get('/{class_id}/delete-comment/{id}/', [
'uses' => 'classroom@getDeleteComment',
'as' => 'Comment.delete',
'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

Second, change your delete link as below:

```
<a href="{{ route('Comment.delete', ['class_id'=>$class_id,'id' => $comment->id]) }}" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Lastly, add the `class_id` parameter to your `getDeleteComment` method:

```
public function getDeleteComment(Request $request,$class_id,$id)
    {
        $comment = StatusComments::where('id', $id)->first();

        $comment->delete();


        Flash::success('Successfuly deleted your comment!');
        return redirect(route('class',['class_id'=>$class_id]));
    }
```

Comment: Now this is the error bro..Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception.

Comment: when does this error shows up ? On delete or before ?

Comment: try removing "'class_id'=>$class_id," from the delete link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123293/discussion-between-shuvo-and-jaysingkar).